# How can I get post data for asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, post

```
<form action="test.aspx" method="post">
<input type"text" name="test[0].myitem" value="computer" />
<input type"text" name="test[0].quantity" value="1" />
<input type"text" name="test[0].price" value="US$10.5" />
<input type"text" name="test[1].myitem" value="printer" />
<input type"text" name="test[1].quantity" value="1" />
<input type"text" name="test[1].price" value="US$15.5" />
</form>
```

this it html source, 
How can I get and use this post data in asp.net c#

`Request.Form["test"]` and
`Request.Form.getValues("test")` didn't work.
`Request.Form["test[0].myitem"]` not work also

Comment: @MEYWD i already test this answer, but It's did't work.

Comment: Edit the question to include what you did and what didn't work

Comment: @MEYWD I'dont know what didn't work. this form working PHP, but ASP.NET is not work.

Comment: change the controls to asp.net controls or add the attribute runat="server" http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_forms.asp

Comment: add the attribute nunat="server", but not working... Please see input name name is "test[0].myitem" "test" name is work. but this "test[0].myitem" name is not work.

Comment: did you add the attribute to all controls?

Comment: show the complete code of the aspx and aspx.cs files

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this

```
string[] keys = Request.Form.AllKeys;
var value = "";
for (int i= 0; i < keys.Length; i++) 
{
   // here you get the name eg test[0].quantity
   // keys[i];
   // to get the value you use
   value = Request.Form[keys[i]];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To get the data you use the `name` of the element as:

```
 Request.Form["test[0].myitem"]
 Request.Form["test[0].quantity"]
```

to see all the posted data you use the `Request.Form.ToString()`

Now, you say that this is not work for you - you have wrong, or some other security of the asp.net did not accept your post back as valid and you get an error.

I just try it on a simple page and works to me.