# Retrieve data sent from a webclient.uploadString using a web handler (ashx)

Tags: asp.net, upload, handler, webclient

I know hot to write an ashx web Handler to receive data sent from a web page through AJAX xhr request.

Now I need to retrieve a string sent from a webclient.UploadString with UTF8 encoding.

Where I'm stuck is I can't find a proper example of how to write the Handler to retrieve the string which has been POSTed...

Any clue welcome. If possible Visual Basic, but c# will do.

Comment: The UploadString is use the POST method.

Comment: use the `Request.Form` to see them all, also read :   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891023/how-can-i-get-post-data-for-asp-net-c-sharp/22891207